Question about ELF storage
I am currently investigating both the ELF and RTEM options for generating log files to further integrate them with another platform (Splunk), currently looking into the impact of these files on the org storage.
I was able to find out where the RTEM logs should be stored (mostly big objects but also some standard objects), but not much about the ELF. I know I can access them going to Event Log File Browser, but do they have an impact on the overall storage?
Thanks a lot!
